# concat displays first and last name but only first name is saved to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have searched online for hours and i cannot find out why if it displays in the form correctly why it doesn't save to the mysql database correctly?

on my form i have a drop down that shows me the student names and i use the following code to get the first and last name for the drop down:

```
<?php
$stud_sql = "SELECT CONCAT (First_name,' ', Last_name) AS fullname FROM students";
$stud_results = mysqli_query($db_conx, $stud_sql);
        echo "<select  name='fullname'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stud_results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $fullname = $row['fullname'];
            echo "<option  value=".$row['fullname'].">" . $row['fullname'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            ?>
```

the drop down on the form displays first name last name perfectly, but when i try to post to my mysql database it only saves the first name instead of both?

following is code for posting to database:

```
if (isset($_POST['fullname']) && ($_POST['fullname'] !='')){
$studentname = $_POST['fullname'];

    if (empty($studentname))
    {
        $errors[] = "Missing student name.";
    }

if (count($errors) > 0)
    {
        //there were validation errors, prepare error message
        $response = "<span style=\"color:red;\">";
        $response .= "the following errors occured:\n";
        $response .= "<ul>";
        $response .= '<li>' .implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li>';
        $response .= "</ul>\n";
        $response .= "</span>\n";
    }
else
    {
        //No validation errors, save the dat to database
        $studentname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $studentname);
$sql = "INSERT INTO incidentform  (`studentname`) value ('$studentname')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

so just to make it clear the concat would display for example funky monkey but only funky would get saved to the database.

ok marc B has suggested these changes which will save the fullname to the database but now only displays 1 name in the drop down?

```
Name of Student:
        <select  name='fullname'>
        <option  value="$id"><?php echo $fullname; ?></option>
        </select>
and
$stud_sql = "SELECT id, CONCAT (First_name,' ', Last_name) AS fullname FROM students";
$stud_results = mysqli_query($db_conx, $stud_sql);


   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stud_results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

            $fullname = $row['fullname'];
}
```

any suggestions on how i can get the full list back?

Comment: Instead of searching online (what you were searching for?) you had to debug this very code.

Comment: ...and **look into page source** as a part of this debugging.

Comment: Now question can be closed as being way too localized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a HTML error.

In this line

```
"<option  value=".$row['fullname'].">"
```

you need to add single quotes between the `$row['fullnane']`....

```
"<option  value='".$row['fullname']."'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using the database correctly. You should be selecting an ID for the student, along with their name, e.g.

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
FROM students
```

and then using

```
<option value="$id">$fullname</option>
```

in your form.

Upon submission, you insert that $id value into your incidentform, and now you've got a link between the incident and a student, based on that common id field. Your system would basically screw over any students who happen to share a name. e.g. "John Smith" (id #42) gets detention, but you only store "John Smith" in the incident report. Now John Smith (#37) and John Smith (#203) are also in trouble.

Comment: I have made the changes you have suggested with the minor change of

Comment: <option value="$id"><?php echo$fullname; ?></option> and i can now add both names to the database bu it only displays 1 name in the list?

Comment: also thought about that as the school only has 80 students its unlikely that 2 students have the same name but even more unlikely is that they will be in the same class as its a special needs school age is not a factor in class formation.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to insert into the field 'studentname' which holds the full name, but you retrieve it from 'First_name' and 'Last_name'. Either you insert the first and last name in the right fields (which I recommend) or you insert the full name in a field.

edit - looks like someone is having fun instantly downvoting answers, grow up.